# Crop image with contours (OpenCV)

Tags: opencv, image-processing

How to crop several parts of an image with contours?
I need a example not in python but in C++.

```
cv::findContours(src, contours, hierarchy, cv::RETR_TREE, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
for (int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++) {
/* crop image src by contours[i] */
}
```

source:
[image]
result:
[image]

Comment: my suggestion is to do **Histogram Backprojection** to suppress the background, then you can do **Labeling** something like `from skimage.measure import label` in python, but I'm not sure how to be done in C++.

Comment: Have you seen [this tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d0c/tutorial_bounding_rects_circles.html)?